# problem with conjunction "than"

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, comparison

In the following sentence-

*Because bureaucracies know more **than** their principals about the work they have been 'contracted' to do, information is asymmetrical.*

Which things are **'than'** comparing?

Comment: I think this sentence should be it, **the work they have been 'contracted' to do**.

Comment: "bureaucracies" vs "their principals", i.e. Bureaucracies know more/their principals know less